# Join a SQL table which could be empty

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I've 3 tables. One table contains some issues. Each issue can have multiple labels:

[image]

An issue can have labels or not. What I'm trying to do is to get all labels when selection all issues. The problem is that when my labels table is empty, no results are returned even the issues table has entries. This is my select:

```
SELECT * FROM issues AS i INNER JOIN objects AS o ON i.related_id = o.related_id INNER JOIN labels AS l ON i.issue_id = l.issue_id WHERE i.tb_id = 2
```

When I remove the label JOIN, I'm getting my expected result. But when I try to JOIN the empty labels table, no results are returned. So there are at the end 2 possible scenarios:

1. Labels table is empty -> return no labels for the issue
2. Labels table is not empty -> return all labels as array or object (I don't know, array would be better I think)

So do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` to `labels` instead of an `INNER JOIN`. Then you will still get results even when no matching rows in `labels`.

Comment: @Nick now I’m getting instead of 2 issues 4 because there are 2 labels for an issue when using left join. Isn’t it possible to get all labels for one issue as array? So that I can loop over the issues and inside the issues over the labels? Option b would be to make another select inside each items loop.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(l.label)` and `GROUP BY i.issue_id`. Dependent on your version of MySQL you might need to group by other fields as well

Comment: Can you may show me the full select with the group? I'm currently trying to learn it and don't get it :/

Comment: `SELECT i.*, o.*, GROUP_CONCAT(l.label) AS labels FROM issues AS i INNER JOIN objects AS o ON i.related_id = o.related_id INNER JOIN labels AS l ON i.issue_id = l.issue_id WHERE i.tb_id = 2 GROUP BY i.issue_id`

Comment: Oh thanks Nick! When I understand it correctly, I'm grouping to get an array, so like a select in a select, right?

Comment: Yes, the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) will give you a comma separated list of labels for each issue, which you can then process in your application

Comment: Alright, I'm trying it right now. I'll let you know when it works!

Comment: Good luck. If you have problems, post a new question.

Comment: I'm getting the list but just one issue now ;D

Comment: Time to post a new question. make sure to include the query, the sample input data that you are using, and the actual and expected output.

Comment: Alright. It happens when an issue don't have labels. I'll post a new one.

Comment: Oops sorry forgot to edit the `JOIN`! try this: `SELECT i.*, o.*, GROUP_CONCAT(l.label) AS labels FROM issues AS i INNER JOIN objects AS o ON i.related_id = o.related_id LEFT JOIN labels AS l ON i.issue_id = l.issue_id WHERE i.tb_id = 2 GROUP BY i.issue_id`

Comment: Now it works! Awesome, thank you sooo much m8. Have a good day and a nice weekend! :)